# Trick in C# with lambda and event

Tags: c#, events, lambda

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to accomplish something like this:

```
Button button = new Button() { OnClick += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("hello") };
```

But it doesn't want to work :D I want to create a control and to add one event to it at the same time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't do this with object initializers, you can do it this way:

```
Func<EventHandler, Button> newButtonWithClick = h =>
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Click += h;
    return b;
};

Button button = newButtonWithClick((sender, e) => MessageBox.Show("hello"));
```

Answer (score 8):

No, object initializers don't allow you to attach event handlers, unfortunately.

The C# team is aware of this limitation - there was some hope that this would be in C# 6, but the feature was dropped. I hope it was dropped due to a lack of time rather than to really lose the feature - maybe we'll see it in C# 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.You can only initialize properties and fields in object initializer. You need to attach the event separately.